# I want to restore all my bookmarks after I have reinstalled

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, restore

I was facing a lot of problems while using Google Chrome as in a lot of adds were coming up which was very annoying . I uninstalled my google chrome and then reinstalled it. I forgot I had so many very important bookmarks. I want them back. I really need them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you researched or attempted so far?

Comment: if you were syncing with your Google Account previously, just log into your Google Account, otherwise you are honestly out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a Google account which you logged into on Chrome, Google has a copy of your browser settings. Open chrome, Open options --> settings and click "Log in to Chrome". Once logged in your browser settings and bookmarks will be loaded into Chrome.